# Can Spatial Analyst extension be used with ArcGIS Server Standard?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcgis-server, modelbuilder, spatial-analyst, license

I have a model written in ModelBuilder that uses a number of tools in Spatial Analyst extension, e.g. Raster Calculator and Focal Statistics, etc.

It runs perfectly with ArcMap. Can I publish it on ArcGIS Server Standard as Geoprocessing service and trigger it from there?

I am with 10.1. Having read the matrix, I found it stated ArcGIS Server Standard only supports Schematic and Network Analysts.

Do I have to run my Model off ArcGIS Server Advanced?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have **[ArcGIS Spatial Analyst for Server](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/arcgisserver/extensions)** to run those functions in a Geoprocessing Service, which is included with the *Advanced* license level.

Here is the **[server functionality matrix for 10.2](http://www.esri.com/library/brochures/pdfs/arcgis-server-functionality-matrix.pdf)**

Comment: +1 I had assumed that the Spatial Analyst extension could be purchased independent of the Advanced license to extend the Standard level but that does not seem (or no longer seems) to be the case.